# htaccess - How to cut some text from url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have simple question about htaccess, but i can't solve it. Part of links of my website on google search has a fragment of url and i don't know how this fragment appeared there? here is an examle:

in google seach is:

`http://dobry-portal.pl/part1-/Tranformers,main,film,0`

real adres is 
`http://www.dobry-portal.pl/Tranformers,main,film,0`

Sometimes adrress on google seach have more than one part between slashes ex. `http://dobry-portal.pl/part1-/part2-/part3-/Tranformers,main,film,0`

How can i simply cut of that parts in htaccess to redirect to real adres `http://www.dobry-portal.pl/Tranformers,main,film,0`

I've tried

> RewriteRule (.*)/part1-/(.*) $1/$2 [L]

but this is not work

Thanks for help,
Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should remove all the "fake subdirectories" between slashes for you:

```
RewriteRule ^.*/([^/,]*,.*) $1 [L,R=301]
```

- `^.*/` greedily matches the path up to the last forward slash
- `([^/,]*,.*)` captures to Group 1...
- `[^/,]*` any characters that are not slashes or commas,
- `,.*` then a comma and he rest of the string
- The `$1` back-reference substitutes Group 1 for the url
- `[L,R=301]` last rule, permanent redirect

I'm sure some tweaks are possible, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/part[0-9]+-)+(.*)$    $1$3 [L]
```

You may also try the RewriteCond pattern:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^(.*)(/part[0-9]+-)+(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^                %1%3 [L]
```

For more details see [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).